# How to create a Duration column in Python from Start and Stop times?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to make a column with time duration (hours - first one would be 1.424 hrs for example). My data looks like this.

[image]

Clock_Start and Clock_Stop are objects.

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
df['Duration'] = (df_nyc['Clock_Stop'] - df['Clock_Start']).astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int)
```

... But I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you need as Duration? seconds? hours?

Comment: Sorry good point... I guess hours would be good!

Comment: You need time AND date to get a duration.  What happens if the start time is before midnight and the end time is after?

Comment: Please post sample data as text, not image. That makes it much more useful an increases chances to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Time alone cannot be added or subtracted. You need to convert to `Timedelta`. There is a stop time that is before the start time, which I assume is because it goes past midnight. In that case, add 24 hours to the result:

```py
h = (pd.to_timedelta(df["Clock_Stop"]) - pd.to_timedelta(df["Clock_Start"])) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
h = h.mask(h < 0, h + 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have something like

```py
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Clock_Start": [time(20,52), time(23,19,55), time(12,17,30)],
                   "Clock_Stop": [time(22,17,27), time(23,41,46), time(3,44)]})

df
  Clock_Start Clock_Stop
0    20:52:00   22:17:27
1    23:19:55   23:41:46
2    12:17:30   03:44:00
```

Note that there is an ambiguity here: row 3, is `03:44:00` on the next day? Or maybe two days later? Or a day before?! That's why you can't just add or subtract *time*. This is true in general, not just if t0 > t1.

But you can remove the ambiguity by using the `timedelta` type and specify for instance that if the difference is negative, assume one day apart, else same day. EX:

```py
# convert datetime.time -> pandas.Timedelta
df["Clock_Start"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Clock_Start"].astype(str))
df["Clock_Stop"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Clock_Stop"].astype(str))

df["Duration"] = df["Clock_Stop"] - df["Clock_Start"]

# df["Duration"]
# 0     0 days 01:25:27
# 1     0 days 00:21:51
# 2   -1 days +15:26:30
# Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df.loc[df["Duration"]<pd.Timedelta(0)] += pd.Timedelta(days=1)
### alternatively ###
# df["Duration"] = np.where((df["Clock_Stop"]-df["Clock_Start"]) > pd.Timedelta(0), 
#                           df["Clock_Stop"]-df["Clock_Start"], 
#                           (df["Clock_Stop"]-df["Clock_Start"]) + pd.Timedelta(days=1))

# df["Duration"]
# 0   0 days 01:25:27
# 1   0 days 00:21:51
# 2   0 days 15:26:30
# Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Now you can get other representations of the duration, e.g. fractional hours like

```py
df["Duration"].dt.total_seconds()/3600
0     1.424167
1     0.364167
2    15.441667
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is awesome! First bit worked perfectly, however with the df.loc part I get the following: "TypeError: Concatenation operation is not implemented for NumPy arrays, use np.concatenate() instead. Please do not rely on this error; it may not be given on all Python implementations."

Do you have any idea why this might be? Thanks again!

Comment: @afroduck not sure if this is related to used package versions (I used pandas 1.4.4, numpy 1.23.3 on Python 3.9.13). You could try to use a numpy.where instead of the df.loc. Added to answer, see comments.